# How to host a php web application on the LAN

Tags: php, web-applications, hosting

i would like to host my php web application on the LAN. Please help me how to host and i should get the details entered by the users into MYSQL.

Thanks
SURYA

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a quick and dirty solution, something like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) or [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) should do what you're looking for. It's a quick and easy platform to build php/mysql applications through windows. They run locally, and can be served over LAN to clients.